# Maven variable : Dollar vs Arobase?

Tags: maven, maven-3

In [this documentation](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html), it is suggested to use "`@{argLine}`". What is the difference between "`@{argLine}`" and "`${argLine}`" ? Is there a scope difference ?

Is this documented in maven doc ? (can't find it...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@{argLine}` instead of the usual `${argLine}` is called "late property evaluation". This is only supported by the Maven Surefire Plugin.

From the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/faq.html#late-property-evaluation):

> How do I use properties set by other plugins in `argLine`?
>
> Maven does property replacement for `${...}` values in pom.xml before any plugin is run. So Surefire would never see the place-holders in its argLine property.
>
> Since the Version 2.17 using an alternate syntax for these properties, `@{...}` allows late replacement of properties when the plugin is executed, so properties that have been modified by other plugins will be picked up correctly.